# Search multiple words in same column on laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, search, eloquent

I need to search multiple words in `title` column in laravel. Like if i search `tea break` then i need to fetch only those rows that title content `tea` and `break`. If any title contain only tea then it will not come on my result. I have added below code but it's fetch only contain one word row too.

```
$query->where('title', 'LIKE', "%$search%");
```

Like if i search `Hello Tea break` then fetch only those row that contain all three words. that is `hello`, `tea`, `break`.

If i search `Hello Tea & break`. In this case i will remove the all spacial characters from my code and make below array add on code.

```
$search = []
$search[0] = 'Hello';
$search[1] = 'Tea';
$search[2] = 'break'
```

Comment: Multiple where clauses of type LIKE should do it

Comment: You are correct but i need to fetch only those titles that contain `tea` and `break`. If any title contain only tea then its come in my code too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could instantiate an array containing your search strings, then use the `->orWhere()` method on the collection to find them.

```
$keywords = ['hello', 'tea', 'break'];
$result = $query->where(function ($query) use ($keywords) {
    foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
       $query->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%");
    }
});
```

Comment: would be `"%$keyword%"`

Comment: Indeed @sta, I just added it.

Comment: does this need to be an "and where" not "or where" as they want results that contain all the keywords, not just some of them?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $search = ['hello', 'tea', 'break'];
    $pages = Page::query();
    foreach ($search as $word) {
        $pages->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $word . '%');
    }
    $pages = $pages->distinct()->get();
```